# Disable Mobile version of SELECT

Tags: jquery, html

I have a SELECT input, with a Searchfield in it. However, when on mobile the mobile browsers will open their mobile version of it, thus also disabling the searchfield. Is there a way to prevent this?

The input is just a jQuery plugin, and the normal SELECT input html.

Greetings,

Comment: No, you'd have to use something else besides a `SELECT` and 'hack' around it.

Answer (score 0):

Give that element the attribute data-role="none". For example:

```
<label for="foo">
<select name="foo" id="foo"  data-role="none">
<option value="a" >A</option>
<option value="b" >B</option>
<option value="c" >C</option>
</select>
```